# HttpServletResponse setStatus not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to throw a custom exception in an OncePerRequestFilter but it is throwing cors error for 4xx codes meanwhile sendError works fine but i cant put a custom body there.

---

This is my code

```
response.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorResponse));
```

---

If i try this it works fine with cors

```
response.sendError(httpStatus.value(),message);
```